# What's wrong with my query? Why every time I click the column button it got an error?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datagridview

The yellow one is the menu and the order summary is the pending table, but every time I click the column button I always got an query error

[image: This is the error]

[image: The yellow one is the menu and the order summary is the pending table, but every time I click the column button I always got an query error]

[image: This is the output]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your problem is with the understanding of parameters and there order. Ps.: Please do not use photos for code examples ...

To do this using parameters, here's the SQL you should use:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Tablename (ID, Name) VALUES (171, @item)";
```

and then you should set its value:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@item", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = items[j];
```

Your error is that, **after** you added the parameter only then you can call:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

So you need to set the parameters first, which should be inserted into your command text.
You can find more infos about **INSERT INTO** on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp) and for more **examples** look at [csharp.hotexamples](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/System.Data.SqlClient/SqlParameter/-/php-sqlparameter-class-examples.html)

Comment: Thank you sir, sorry for posting pictures. Still new here but all the mistake I made will make help me to be good. Thank you Sir @Nanoserver

Comment: Is it not allowed to answer to down voted questions or why did I get these? Good if I could help you and no problem with the image, because I'm new too...